# how can I find $x,y$ in the following equation and showing linear independence of the result?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Here is the equation I want to solve rigorously:

$2r + (1 + \sqrt{-5})s = 0$

**A trial:**

1-I know that the solutions intuitively are $(-1 - \sqrt{-5}, 2)$ and $(-3, 1 - \sqrt{-5})$ but I do not know the rigorous way of finding the solution. So, can anyone help me in that direction ?

2- Also, I want to show that $(-1 - \sqrt{-5}, 2),(-3, 1 - \sqrt{-5})$ are linearly independent, could someone show me the details of this please?

Comment: How about (0,0) as a solution? And multiples of the answers you offered?

Comment: So we have infinitely many solution @Math777 .... but those are the only linearly independent ones ..... Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{split}2r+(1+\sqrt 5i)s&=0\\
2r&=-(1+\sqrt 5i)s\end{split}$$

Set $r=-(1+\sqrt 5i),s=2$ is a solution because you sort of take the thing that's on the other side and set it to be the variable on the side.

But to find all the solutions,

$$r=-\frac 1 2(1+\sqrt 5i)s$$

Then

$$\left(\begin{matrix}-\frac 1 2(1+\sqrt5i)s\\s\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-\frac 1 2(1+\sqrt5i)\\1\end{matrix}\right)s$$

is the set of solutions.

There's more unknowns than equations, so the solution isn't unique. You can only have a unique solution if there are at least as many equations as unknowns.

**Linear independence**

You wanted to show that the two of your vectors are linearly independent, this means they are not scalar multiples of one another.

$$\begin{split}(-1-\sqrt 5 i, 2)&=c(-3,1-\sqrt 5 i)\\
-1-\sqrt 5 i+3c&=0\text { the first component}\\
c&=\frac 1 3(1+\sqrt 5 i)\\
2&=(1-\sqrt 5 i)c\text { the second component}\\
&=(1-\sqrt 5 i)\frac 1 3(1+\sqrt 5 i)\\
&=\frac 1 3(1+5)=2\end{split}$$

Therefore, the first vector is $c=\frac 1 3 (1+\sqrt 5 i)$ times the second vector. This means they are linearly *dependent*. This makes sense because both of them are solutions to the system, but the solution space has only dimension 1, so any two solutions will line on the same "line".

If you wanted to show that two vectors $v_1, v_2$ were linearly independent, you would show that $v_1\ne cv_2$ for all choices of c.

Comment: What about the other part of the question?

Comment: @Confusion I forgot about it, see edits

Comment: for your justification of the second vector , my equation contains $2r$ not $3r$.

Comment: right! the second vector *is* actually a solution, and linearly *dependent* to the first one. sorry about that.

Comment: how did u know that the solution space(do you mean the null space by the solution space) has only one vector?

Comment: it doesn't have just one vector, it has infinitely many vectors of the form $\left(\begin{matrix}-\frac 1 2(1+\sqrt5i)\\1\end{matrix}\right)s, s\in \mathbb C$. any vector that is a multiple of the vector I have written there satisfies the original equation. no by solution space i just mean the solutions for the equation

Comment: But they should be independent, I mean   $(-1 - \sqrt{-5}, 2)$ and $(-3, 1 - \sqrt{-5}).$ how can you get (in the second coordinate of both) $2$ from $1 - \sqrt{-5}$?

Comment: by multiplying by $c=\frac 1 3 (1+\sqrt 5 i)$. $\frac 1 3 (1+\sqrt 5 i)*(1-\sqrt 5 i)=\frac 1 3(1^2-5*(-1))=\frac 1 3(6)=2$ in general, you can get rid of an imaginary part by multiplying by its complex conjugate.

Comment: Okay that make sense.